# Defining date cycles via a Boolean in PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Consider the following table consisting of a *Date* and *Item* column:

| Date | Item |
| --- | --- |
| April 2 | X |
| April 3 | X |
| April 5 | X |
| April 11 | X |
| April 12 | X |
| April 14 | X |
| April 20 | X |
| April 2 | Y |
| April 3 | Y |
| April 9 | Y |
| April 11 | Y |
| April 12 | Y |
| April 14 | Y |

I would like to add an additional column called *StartFlag* containing Boolean values that indicate if an item "entered" this list, and by "enter" we understand the following:

An item **"enters"** the list if it was not on the list for the past 5 days.

Hence, the above table should result in the following:

| Date | Item | StartFlag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| April 2 | X | TRUE |
| April 3 | X | FALSE |
| April 5 | X | FALSE |
| April 11 | X | TRUE |
| April 12 | X | FALSE |
| April 14 | X | FALSE |
| April 20 | X | TRUE |
| April 2 | Y | TRUE |
| April 3 | Y | FALSE |
| April 9 | Y | TRUE |
| April 11 | Y | FALSE |
| April 12 | Y | FALSE |
| April 14 | Y | FALSE |

Does someone have a solution for this problem in PowerQuery?

**I have posted this question some days ago and I have received a working solution in DAX but unfortunately it turned out I require a PowerQuery solution :(**

Thank you. -- JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have your data in a proper format in an listobject in Excel like that

[image]

Then I used the following function `fxEntered` to add a column to the input table `tblInput`

This is the M-code for the `tblInput`

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblInput"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Item", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "StartFlag", each fxEntered([Date], [Item]))
in
    #"Invoked Custom Function"
```

This is the M-Code for the function `fxEntered`

```
  (inpDate as date, item as text) =>
let    
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblInput"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Item", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Date] < inpDate and [Item] = item),
    max = List.Max(#"Filtered Rows"[Date]),
    result = try if Number.From(inpDate) - Number.From(max) < 5 then false else true otherwise true
in
    result
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this not only solved my problem but also taught me a lot as a total beginner.